# How to remove UserName field from asp.net core 3 Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, identity

I wanna use phoneNumber field as a unique field and remove UserName
Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You cannot modify the default `IdentityUser` model. However, you can treat the phone number as the user name, as using email for user name works, i.e. you simply just make it the value of `UserName` as well. For example, when using email as username, both `Email` and `UserName` hold the email address. Simply do the same with your phone number. Make the phone number the value of `UserName`, and then you're good to go.